# laravel scout full text search installation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

while installing the laravel/scout in my laravel 5 app, am getting error.

I have run the following command in putty

```
composer require laravel/scout
```

And I got the following error message:

```
 php artisan clear-compiled
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Killed
```

Any idea why am getting this error message.

Comment: this is only happening when you add laravel/scout? remove the dependency and `clear-compiled` again. Also, make sure you have enough memory, sometimes the process gets killed if you're running out of memory.

Comment: @ali this is happening with laravel/scout only...few days back I have installed,maatwebsite excel package which went well. But, this laravel/scout is creating issue. How to check the memory available in my laravel hosting

Comment: I'm not sure if this is of any help, [check this reported issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1815)